# How to download a picture from a URL and make it bitmap in kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

```
var bitmap1: Bitmap? = null
var url = "https://i.ibb.co/F3k0101/hero-man.png"
```

How to put a picture from Url inside the bitmap1 variable?

Comment: If your ultimate goal is to load the bitmap in an ImageView then you should really look into [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide)

Comment: that's the thing, I don't need to upload to ImageView, I need a Bitmap format variable  @mightyWOZ

Comment: You could still use Glide for this, you'd just apply the bitmap to a custom target or use `submit().get()` on the request to block.

Comment: @PPartisan how do I write this to a variable later?

Comment: If it's synchronous, you just assign the value returned from `get` to a variable. Of course, you need to be conscious of threading if you use this.